# ¿Cómo capturar el value de un <button> con Javascript?

Tags: javascript, mvc

Como exprese necesito capturar el valor del `value` de mi `<button>`.

Es decir, en mi caso seria capturar el valor que tiene **"cont"** en el `value` de mi `<button>`desde mi función `deleteRow(this)`.

En esta  `<td>` se encuentra el`botón`:

```
 table += '<td><button onclick="deleteRow(this);"'+" class='boton2 btn' id='btnEliminar'" + " value=" + cont + ">Eliminar</button></td>";
```

Por las dudas les dejo la tabla completa:

```
 var table = '<table cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="tablaSeleccionados"><thead bgcolor="#2E4053"><tr><th scope="col" style="color:#ECF0F1">Libros seleccionados</th><th scope="col" style="color:#ECF0F1">Accion</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr></tr>';

        for (var i = 0; i < cantNames; i++) {

            table += '<tr>';
            table += '<td>' + names[i] + '</td>';
            //en la linea siguiente COMO CAPTURO EL VALOR QUE TIENE cont en el value para pasarselo a la funcion deleteRow(this)??
            table += '<td><button onclick="deleteRow(this);"'+" class='boton2 btn' id='btnEliminar'" + " value=" + cont + ">Eliminar</button></td>";
            //table += '<td><button class="boton2 btn" id="btnEliminar"'+" value="+ idBook[i] +">Eliminar</button></td>";

            //10/03
            //table += '<td><button onclick="deleteRow(this,' + "'" + idBook[i] + "'" + ',' + "'" + names[i] + "')" + "class='boton2 btn' id='btnEliminar'" + " value=" + cont + ">Eliminar</button></td>";
            table += '</tr>';
            cont++;
        };

        table += '</tbody></table>';
```

Acá la funcion `deleteRow()`

```
function deleteRow(r) {
  var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
  document.getElementById("tablaSeleccionados").deleteRow(i);//no borrar
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el `button` estas asignado en el evento `onclick` la ejecución de `deleteRow(this);`.

La variable `this` en el contexto de ejecución del `onclick` es exactamente la referencia al botón mismo.

Por ende, para obtener el `value` del `button` presionado solo necesitas hacer `r.value`

#### Ejemplo:

```js
function deleteRow(r) {
  console.log('Elemento que disparo el evento: ', r);
  console.log('Value del elemento: ', r.value);
}
```

```html
<button value="hola" onclick="deleteRow(this)">Eliminar</button>
```

Comment: Gracias @Marcos!!